# How to cycle through elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jQuery code that acts on some HTML tabs, clears the section elements of the content-current class, then adds content-current class to the content I want shown. It also clears the tabs of their tab-current class and adds the tab-current class to one I clicked. This code itself works and does everything I need:

```
$('a.tab1').click(function() {
    $('section').removeClass('content-current');
    $('#section-1').addClass('content-current');
    $('a').removeClass('tab-current');
    $('a.tab1').addClass('tab-current');
});

$('a.tab2').click(function() {
    $('section').removeClass('content-current');
    $('#section-2').addClass('content-current');
    $('a').removeClass('tab-current');
    $('a.tab2').addClass('tab-current');
});

$('a.tab3').click(function() {
    $('section').removeClass('content-current')
    $('#section-3').addClass('content-current')
    $('a').removeClass('tab-current');
    $('a.tab3').addClass('tab-current');
});

$('a.tab4').click(function() {
    $('section').removeClass('content-current')
    $('#section-4').addClass('content-current')
    $('a').removeClass('tab-current');
    $('a.tab4').addClass('tab-current');
});

$('a.tab5').click(function() {
    $('section').removeClass('content-current')
    $('#section-5').addClass('content-current')
    $('a').removeClass('tab-current');
    $('a.tab5').addClass('tab-current');
});
```

Obviously this is very repetitive and most likely my noobiness with jQuery is showing. I've done some research but can't figure out how to cycle through an HTML collection with jQuery to refactor this. Am I able to use for each or lodash for each on jQuery objects? Any pointers or resources would be helpful. Thank you!

html code tabs:

```
<li><a href="#section-1" class="tab1 tab-current"><span>  Shop</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#section-2" class="tab2"><span>  Drinks</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#section-3" class="tab3"><span>  Food</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#section-4" class="tab4"><span>  Lab</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#section-5" class="tab5"><span>  Order</span></a></li>
```

Content html:

```
<section id="section-1" class="content-current">
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/01.png" alt="img01" />
        <h3>Sushi Gumbo Beetroot</h3>
        <p>Sushi gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/02.png" alt="img02" />
        <h3>Pea Sprouts Fava Soup</h3>
        <p>Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/03.png" alt="img03" />
        <h3>Turnip Broccoli Sashimi</h3>
        <p>Nori grape silver beet broccoli kombu beet greens fava bean potato quandong celery. Bunya nuts black-eyed pea prairie turnip leek lentil turnip greens parsnip.</p>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="section-2">
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/04.png" alt="img04" />
        <h3>Asparagus Cucumber Cake</h3>
        <p>Chickweed okra pea winter purslane coriander yarrow sweet pepper radish garlic brussels sprout groundnut summer purslane earthnut pea tomato spring onion azuki bean gourd. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/05.png" alt="img05" />
        <h3>Magis Kohlrabi Gourd</h3>
        <p>Salsify taro catsear garlic gram celery bitterleaf wattle seed collard greens nori. Grape wattle seed kombu beetroot horseradish carrot squash brussels sprout chard.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/06.png" alt="img06" />
        <h3>Ricebean Rutabaga</h3>
        <p>Celery quandong swiss chard chicory earthnut pea potato. Salsify taro catsear garlic gram celery bitterleaf wattle seed collard greens nori. </p>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="section-3">
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/02.png" alt="img02" />
        <h3>Noodle Curry</h3>
        <p>Lotus root water spinach fennel kombu maize bamboo shoot green bean swiss chard seakale pumpkin onion chickpea gram corn pea.Sushi gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/06.png" alt="img06" />
        <h3>Leek Wasabi</h3>
        <p>Sushi gumbo beet greens corn soko endive gumbo gourd. Parsley shallot courgette tatsoi pea sprouts fava bean collard greens dandelion okra wakame tomato.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/01.png" alt="img01" />
        <h3>Green Tofu Wrap</h3>
        <p>Pea horseradish azuki bean lettuce avocado asparagus okra. Kohlrabi radish okra azuki bean corn fava bean mustard tigernut wasabi tofu broccoli mixture soup.</p>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="section-4">
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/03.png" alt="img03" />
        <h3>Tomato Cucumber Curd</h3>
        <p>Chickweed okra pea winter purslane coriander yarrow sweet pepper radish garlic brussels sprout groundnut summer purslane earthnut pea tomato spring onion azuki bean gourd. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/01.png" alt="img01" />
        <h3>Mushroom Green</h3>
        <p>Salsify taro catsear garlic gram celery bitterleaf wattle seed collard greens nori. Grape wattle seed kombu beetroot horseradish carrot squash brussels sprout chard.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="mediabox">
        <img src="img/04.png" alt="img04" />
        <h3>Swiss Celery Chard</h3>
        <p>Celery quandong swiss chard chicory earthnut pea potato. Salsify taro catsear garlic gram celery bitterleaf wattle seed collard greens nori. </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: would be great if you can post the html as well

Comment: No problem! I just didn't wanna make it crazy long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('a[class^="tab"]').on('click', function() {
    $('section').removeClass('content-current');
    $($(this).attr('href')).addClass('content-current');
    $('a').removeClass('tab-current');
    $(this).addClass('tab-current');
});
```

1. `[class^="tab"]`: Will select all the elements whose class starts with `tab`. ex. `tab1`, `tab2`, etc.
2. `$(this).attr('href')`: Will get the `href` attribute of the clicked link. ex. `#section-1` for the first link
3. `$(this)`: Is the clicked link

Comment: I think this solution is the most elegant and it certainly works, if you don't mind could you go into detail about the first and the third lines? Those are the only ones I don't understand.

Answer (score 4):

### Some general clues

About your HTML

- I suggest never to use `id`s for this purpose. What happens if someone asks you to put two of these tab controls below each other on the same page? Then a collegaue has to modify the code and makes a mistake and boom, you end up with colliding `id`s on your page. **Use data attributes instead.**

About using jQuery:

- Save your selectors in variables instead of always searching for them. This will make your code faster and also makes it look more consistent.
- Put the event handler on the element that contains the tabs (see below)
- When finding the element the user clicked on, use the `this` keyword. Then save it into a jQuery variable using `$(this)`

### A possible solution

Assuming that you have a `.tabcontainer` element that your `a`s are in and the `a`s have a `tab` class and your `a`s have a data attribue called `data-tabid` that identifies which tabs they are pointing to and that the tabs themselves have a `data-tabid` attribute that identifies them, here is how I would do it:

```
var $sections = $("section");
var $allLinks = $(".tabcontainer a.tab");
$('.tabcontainer').on('click', 'a.tab', function() {
    // Get the <a> you clicked on
    var $this = $(this);
    // Get the current tab id
    var currentTabId = $this.attr('data-tabid');

    // Remove class from all sections
    $sections.removeClass('content-current');
    // Find current section
    var $currentSection = $sections.filter('[data-tabid=' + currentTabId + ']')
                                   .addClass('content-current');

    // Remove clas from all links
    $allLinks.removeClass('tab-current');
    // Add class to current link
    $this.addClass('tab-current');
});
```

Here is my suggestion to modify your html:

```
<ul class="tabcontainer">
    <li><a href="#section-1" class="tab tab-current" data-tabid="1"><span>Shop</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-2" class="tab" data-tabid="2"><span>Drinks</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-3" class="tab" data-tabid="3"><span>Food</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-4" class="tab" data-tabid="4"><span>Lab</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#section-5" class="tab" data-tabid="5"><span>Order</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And the sections:

```
<section class="content-current" data-tabid="1">...</section>
<section data-tabid="2">...</section>
<section data-tabid="3">...</section>
<section data-tabid="4">...</section>
```

Comment: I really appreciate this answer as well because I wasn't even aware of data attributes with HTML, something I'm certain to research and add into my code. I wish I could choose both your answers. Thanks for educating a newbsicle like myself!

Comment: @MichaelPascuzzi You're welcome. :) Please also ready my thoughts on how to improve your usage of jQuery. :)

Comment: I did! And it will certainly be incorporated, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Change tabs like this one:

```
<li><a href="#section-3" class="tab" data-tab-id="3"><span>  Food</span></a></li>
```

And then your JS code would look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab', function() {
  var sectionId = $.data(this, 'section-id');
  $('.content-current').removeClass('content-current')
  $('#section-' + sectionId ).addClass('content-current')
  $('.tab-current').removeClass('tab-current');
  $(this).addClass('tab-current');
});
```

Documentation: [$.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/), [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)